# Download menu pops up after every new tab is opened

Tags: menu, downloads, dropbox

I recently installed Dropbox on Ubuntu, the install went perfectly fine and Dropbox is functioning normally. However, now every time I open a new tab in Firefox I am promoted with the download menu for the dropbox .deb package even though I already have it installed. I've tried re-downloading, saving, opening, everything.

Thanks!
Drew

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  In the address bar, type about:config and press Enter. Click I'll be careful, I promise!, to continue to the about:config page.

[image]

Type browser.new in the search box, and double-click the browser.newtab.url preference and change the Value to about:newtab

[image]